# How to loop through a Table, find a value and insert if exists?

Tags: t-sql

I've two table: 
 Table A
   ID   Field1 ....

Table B
   ID   Field2 Field3 ...

I would like to LOOP through table B and if a a record with same ID exits in table A, add the value Field2 and Field3 in Table A.

I don't know how to do in T-SQL!

Comment: "FOR loop in T-SQL" - don't do it m'ok! Sets, Sets, Sets......You can never have enough Sets!

Comment: The corresponding notion for "looping" through records in a table (or subset thereof) is a CURSOR.  There are various types of cursors, depending on what locking you require, etc.

Comment: Do you want compose the Field1 field in table A with the values Field2 and Field3 from table B? Or do Field2 and Field3 exist in table A as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a loop construction is not necessary for this update, you can solve it in a neater way by using set operations. If I understand the question correctly you want to [UPDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) table A with the values from table B. Use a query like this:

```
UPDATE TableA
  SET TableA.Field2 = TableB.Field2, TableA.Field3 = TableB.Field3
  FROM TableB
  WHERE TableA.ID = TableB.ID
```

You might wanna do an extra check in this query to see what the values in field 2 and 3 in table A are before replacing them.

(To test first what the results of this query will be, build a SELECT query from the UPDATE query above!)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN TableA.ID IS NULL THEN TableB.Field2
    ELSE TableB.Field3
END as FieldX
FROM TableB LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA
        ON TableA.ID = TableB.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can do it simply like this:

```
select tab2.id, (tab2.field2 + tab2.field3) as sumfield 
from tab2 join tab1 on tab2.id = tab1.id
```

OR

```
select tab2.id, (tab2.field2 + tab2.field3) as sumfield 
from tab2 
join 
(select distinct id from tab1) tab1
on tab2.id = tab1.id
```